# Positioning a node in the beginning of the line

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I am beginner in Latex
I've been trying for a day to draw a super simple straight line with three nodes on that. it goes fine but when I see the pdf. the beginning node doesn't start from the beginning of the line. it's a bit on the right side compared to a paragraph above it. I am so frustrated not to be able to control it.

Please don't make this question as a duplicate one I searched a lot couldn't find the answer.

The code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[red] 
(0,0)   circle (2pt) node[blue,above]{$bin_1$}  --
(15,0)  circle (2pt) node[blue,above] {$bin_{nyquist}$}     -- 
(7,0)   circle (2pt) node[blue,above] {$k_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I meant coordinate (0,0). It is not the beginning of the line it's a bit in the right side compared to the paragraph above it. how can force it to go to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The coordinates inside a `tikzpicture` is only relative to the other things inside the `tikzpicture`, so `(0,0)` has no direct connection to the start of the line. The first node label (`$bin_1$`) will probably extend to the left of (0,0).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for your comment. how can i shift it to the left then?

Comment: If the picture starts a paragraph, it will be indented; add `\noindent` to remove it, or put the picture into a `flushleft` environment. The remaining indentation is the border of the label `{$bin_1$}`; if you change it to `node[blue,above,inner sep=0mm]{$bin_1$}` this indentation is also gone. But now the label is too close to the node, so you need `node[blue,above,inner sep=0mm,yshift=0.5ex]{$bin_1$}` to counter act that.

Comment: Essentially, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176723/align-tikzpicture-to-body-text-with-node-as-reference/176727#176727 See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12455/586 for more explanation of what happens (if needed).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. with links give whole picture of the issue thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just the start of your diagram, it might be worthwhile to define the circles as nodes and to associate the labels explicitly. The code is longer, but more flexible and more structured.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
XXX%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  [mynode/.style={circle,fill=green,minimum width=5pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
   mylabel/.style={blue,inner sep=0mm,label distance=0.5ex}
  ]
\node[mynode,label={[mylabel]$bin_1$}]                  (a) at (0,0) {};
\node[mynode,label={[mylabel]$k_1$}]                    (b) at (2,0) {};
\node[mynode,label={[mylabel]$bin_{\mathrm{nyquist}}$}] (c) at (4,0) {};
\draw[red] (a) -- (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}%
XXX
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I will chose this! . but the point of the question solved by "flushleft"